# Проверка ошибок соединения на клиенте

Tags: golang, tcp

Тестирую свой микросервис, но не могу понять как отловить некоторые ошибки соединения.  Например, сервис "отвалился", получаю "dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3000: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".  Но как ее отловить на клиенте?  Ниже попытки, которые не работают:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time" 
    "net/http"
    //"net/url"
    //"errors"
)

func main() {
    for {
        urlPath := fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:3000/converter/html?file=%s", "1.docx")
        resp, err := http.Get(urlPath)
        // запрос клиента когда сервис не был запущен
        //*url.Error  &url.Error{Op:"Get", URL:"http://localhost:3000/converter/html?file=1.docx", Err:(*net.OpError)(0xc0001a4050)}
        fmt.Printf("%v %T  %#v \n", resp, err, err)
        // как вытащить самую внутреннюю ошибку?
        //fmt.Printf("%v \n", err.Unwrap()) // не работает  - нет такого метода, хотя он есть
        //fmt.Printf("%s %v\n", err.Err, err.Op) // не работает  - нет таких полей, хотя они есть
        //if errors.Is(err, url.Error) {     // не работает 
        //    fmt.Println(err)
        //}

        time.Sleep(1000)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`errors.As`:

```golang
if err != nil {
    var uerr *url.Error
    if errors.As(err, &uerr) {
        log.Println(uerr.Err, uerr.Op)
    }
}
```

Помимо этого, для создания *URL* надо использовать пакет
`net/url`,
а `time.Sleep(1000)` — явная ошибка, так
как надо использовать `time.Millisecond` и ему подобные.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. На As я уже сам успел исправить, но все равно спасибо. Код не является реально используемым - это просто тестовый пример для проверки ошибки, которая возникала в реальном коде. Ну а time.Sleep с литералом просто недосмотр.